# Optimization of geojson data in Cesium viewer

Tags: cesium

I am trying to build an application that shows a globe with country borders along with US state boundaries. For US state boundaries, I follow https://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/ and World country boundaries from https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::world-countries/explore?location=46.701655%2C-92.188198%2C7.07

Using Cesium to load the map and it is taking more than a minute to plot the same. Any idea to optimize the same?

I tried converting the GeoJSON file to TopoJSON. Also used the  https://github.com/node-geojson/geojson-pick  to pick the specific key from the GeoJSON file. Both are not giving proper solution.

Code snippet to load the map is given below

```
 this.viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(--path--,{
        stroke: Cesium.Color.SILVER,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fill: new Cesium.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
      }));
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You had a tag for ArcGIS 10.1 but do not appear to be using that software so I removed it.

Comment: How large is the geojson file (filesize in megabytes)?

Comment: geojson file size is 370MB. I am able to convert it to topojson with 320MB. Still the problem persists